# When should I use the word 'yo' in a sentence where the verb conjugation already shows that I am the subject?

Tags: pronombres, verbos, sintaxis

Early on while I was learning Spanish, my teachers would always make us use the pronoun 'yo' even if it was redundant:

> Yo pienso que...
>   Yo quiero...
>   Yo hablo...
>   etc.

However, a more advanced Spanish book I bought told me only to use redundant pronouns like yo when I wanted to emphasize that ***I*** was performing the action (and when clarification of the subject was necessary).

When should I use 'yo' in my sentences in Spanish? Does it make me sound rather self centered if I use it constantly? How and when do native speakers use it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use the pronoun when it clarifies an ambiguity:

> Leería el libro.

This is vague without further context. It could mean "I would read the book" or "He/she would read the book."  So the addition of a pronoun (or other context) is necessary.

Or use a pronoun for emphasis.

> Él leyó el libro.  Yo leí la revista.
>
> "He read the book. *I* read the magazine."

Adding the pronoun all the time isn't really harmful, but it make make it appear that you're emphasising the pronoun when you don't intend to.

Comment: In _Comería una manzana_ dativo ético is often used: _Me comería una manzana_

Comment: _Yo no comí nada_ btw. Double negative, I know...

Comment: With comer, dativo ético is often used, quite rare to use comer without it (at least in Spain). For example, instead of "Él comió una naranja" "Se comió una naranja". Don't ask why, it is just that way.

Comment: Hrm, I wasn't aware of that.  I'll change my answer to use a different verb... and listen for that in the future.

Comment: Additionally, and in line with the current examples: *Yo leí la revista* means that I read a few pages in the magazine, not necessarilly all of them. But *Yo me leí la revista* would mean that I read it cover to cover.

Comment: @Serabe: Is "comer" just an odd verb in that it uses the ethical dative frequently, or is there a rule to using the ethical dative in certain contexts?

Comment: @Aprendedor: That would be a good question to ask :)

Answer (score 5):

I think the book explanation is good. But for simplicity use it at the beginning of the paragraph (to clarify it's you) and no more.

For example

> I think it's important because I want to be able to do it.
>
> Yo creo que es importante porque quiero ser capaz de hacerlo.

Also, the verb itself told you if its explicit the need to use the "Yo". Using your example when you say quiero you're talking about you:

> Yo quiero
>
> (Ella/El) quiere
>
> Tu quieres
>
> Nosotros queremos
>
> Vosotros quereis
>
> Ellos quieren

And so on

Answer (score 3):

Besides clarification as the other answers had pointed out, there's also another use: to add emphasis on that something is personal, for example, expressing opinions:

> Yo lo haría de esta forma...
>
> Yo opino lo contrario

Answer (score 1):

There is no strict rule on this. You can always use `yo` in your phrases without seeming self centered (that is more an attitude, not a linguistic use).

Answer (score 0):

Mainly for emphasis, but specially some people use it on the *pretérito imperfecto* where there is an ambiguity over the first and third singular forms.

> *Yo decía*
>
> *Él decía*
>
> *Saltaba sobre la cama* (I jumped on the bed / He jumped on the bed)

I rather specify the third person over the first as I don't like to use «*yo*» unless I feel the need to make an emphasis.

Answer (score 0):

Redundancy, as in :

> Yo no se si tu me comprendes a mi lo que yo te estoy diciendo a ti.