# Do fluent Spanish Speakers say the pronoun when speaking?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, méxico

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When should I use the word 'yo' in a sentence where the verb conjugation already shows that I am the subject?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/134/when-should-i-use-the-word-yo-in-a-sentence-where-the-verb-conjugation-already)

I was wondering if fluent Spanish Speakers say the pronoun when they are speaking.  For example, do they say.

> Yo tengo un perro.

Or do they say.

> Tengo un perro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are valid but it depends on the person, and the place. For example the Yo tengo un perro will be really common in Uruguay while Where the use of "YO" is really strong. Tengo un perro will be more used in Argentina, despite that you can't say that is a "regional" difference. As I say both are correct. Pherhaps the main difference comes clear here:

If you ask, "Do you have a dog?"

> - Q: ¿Tienes un perro?
> - A: Sí, tengo un perro.

In that case ("**Yo** tengo un perro"), the "yo" would be redundant

If you ask, "Who has a dog?"

> - Q: ¿Quién tiene un perro?
> - A: Yo tengo un perro.

I hope this makes it clear.

Comment: Ah, yes.  Wonderful.

Comment: But be careful of do not overuse "yo".  It may be considered a sign of strong  egocentric feelings.  ;)