# What is the "dativo ético"?

Tags: gramática

In [this comment](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/134/when-should-i-use-the-word-yo-in-a-sentence-where-the-verb-conjugation-already#comment147_140), the grammatical term *dativo ético* is mentioned:

> With comer, dativo ético is often used, quite rare to use comer without it (at least in Spain). For example, instead of "Él comió una naranja" "Se comió una naranja". Don't ask why, it is just that way.

What is this and when is it used?

Comment: Related: the canonical q-a https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/26171/9385

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The English term is *ethic dative*. It's a dative form which often appears in Latin but is very rare in English.

The ethic dative is applied to pronouns and expresses a certain interest in a matter. You probably know the English expression "Cry me a river" which is a pretty good example. You use this saying to tell you don't care, so here it's rather disinterest than interest. The pronoun "me" is not solely a "true" dative (whom) but also put emphasis on the (dis)interest.

Comment: ¿Hay ejemplos en español que puedes darme también?

Comment: @wbyoung I'm afraid I cannot offer an appropriate example yet (I could make one up (by translating common example of my mother-tongue to Spanish) but I cannot guarantee it being good). I will add examples when I come across some good examples.

Comment: It's already been a year, but, like in English, most instances of the ethic dative are very colloquial and will probably be regional. Something I'd say: "No te me las llevés de tan fuerte" (_Don't act so strong_ and _me_ being the dative object). Another example I found online (that doesn't sound natural to me): "No me seas tan tonto".

Comment: @clinch I agree. In my native language this is very informal, too, and afaik also only used in a few dialects.

Comment: minor correction: the correct adjective in English is "ethical", not "ethic".

Comment: @AlanEvangelista "Ethical dative" is probably more common, but some sources consider "ethic" a valid alternative. I do remember that I looked up the English term back then, but I can't tell you what sources I used. Anyways, feel free to edit my post if you think it should be fixed, for me it's just too minor. (Although I could also fix the last sentence of my post...)

Answer (score 5):

[Dativo](http://lema.rae.es/desen/?key=dativo)

> Caso de la declinación latina y de otras lenguas que en español equivale al objeto indirecto del verbo.

En Español existen tres tipos de Dativos

~ ético.

> Pronombre no necesario para el sentido de la frase, que designa a la persona afectada por la acción o interesada por ella. «Los dativos éticos son incompatibles con los verbos transitivos cuyo objeto directo contenga un sustantivo que no lleve artículo ni ningún otro elemento modificador, lo que con frecuencia se atribuye a factores aspectuales, más concretamente al efecto del dativo ético sobre el modo de acción verbal. Observe que podemos decir Juan se sabe la lección, pero no diríamos *Juan se sabe geografía. Decimos, análogamente, me bebí la leche, pero no decimos *me bebí leche.»
>
> No ***me*** come la verdura (dicho por la madre acerca del hijo)
>
> ***Se*** le desmayó allí delante,
>
> ¡Pero ... ¿qué ***me*** ha hecho?! (cuando alguien hace algo que no debe)

~ posesivo.

> En ciertas lenguas, dativo que designa al poseedor en las oraciones nominales.
>
> ***Le*** rompieron un brazo (le = su)
>
> ***Le*** robaron la cartera (le = su)

~ simpatético.

> En ciertas lenguas, dativo que indica relación personal en oraciones nominales y que presenta un valor próximo al dativo posesivo.
>
> ***lo*** llores porque se me parte el corazón (por se parte mi corazón)
>
> ***le*** salí al encuentro (al encuentro de él);
>
> ***se*** notaba las manos temblonas (notaba sus manos)

[Ejemplos de los tres tipos de Dativos](http://hispanoteca.eu/Lexikon%20der%20Linguistik/c/COMPLEMENTO%20INDIRECTO.htm)

Comment: How does it differ from standard dative? In #1, who does each _se_ refer to? The subject? If so, why use it? Just for the emotional emphasis? In #2, who is studying? Someone the speaker's talking to (a student perhaps)? Again, how does that differ from regular dative?

Comment: This is straight from [another source](http://endrino.pntic.mec.es/~hotp0056/a_casas/Dativo_4..htm).

Comment: @wbyoung answer update, at the end you can see a link with example of the three types of dative in Spanish