# Se les puso nerviosa - meaning of "les"

Tags: pronombres

What does exactly "les" means in "Se les puso nerviosa"? Did she get angry *with* them, *while with* them or are they just *concerned* with the fact that she got angry ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means in general that the fact that she got nervous affected them in some way. It might mean that she got angry at them, or that they all did some risky activity together and she had some nervous attack which hindered the activity, for example. Again, see [dativo ético](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/4468/24236).

Comment: I was not sure if it was used to express they were the target of her anger, if they were worried with her or a more general relation between them and her anger. Your answer made it clear it is the last case. Thanks!

Comment: Alan, both in the question and in the previous comment you mention "anger" but *nerviosa* is nervous, worried, distressed but not angry.

Comment: @DGaleano Right. I often get confused with that because "nervoso" can mean both "nervous" and "angry" in Portuguese, my native language. Thanks for pointing it out! Anyway, the reason of her being nervous can be "them" or something else in my example sentence, that's what was unclear to me before.