# ¿Por qué se llama "dativo ético"?

Tags: gramática, uso-de-palabras

Ahora que están apareciendo varias preguntas sobre el dativo ético, me ha surgido la duda de por qué se llama así.

En el ejemplo

> El niño se **me** durmió mientras le explicaba el ejercicio

entiendo que *me* es un *dativo* (léase "complemento indirecto"). Pero, ¿por qué es *ético*?

Comment: Related: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/4464/1821

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La caracterización del "dativo ético" viene ya de la gramática latina, aunque el tal *datīvus ēthicus* latino parece haber permitido más usos que el del castellano. El significado de *ēthicus* es "que tiene que ver con la moral o con la expresión del carácter personal", "que involucra a la moral".

En este caso "ético" se usa en el sentido de "que incluye un interés personal, que involucra emocionalmente". El dativo ético es una marca de interés de la persona referenciada por la acción que expresa la frase. Como tal, no es parte esencial de la estructura gramatical de la frase (no es un complemento indirecto "de verdad" como el de los verbos ditransitivos), y por eso se la puede omitir cambiando la connotación pero no el significado básico de la proposición.

*“El niño se durmió”* no incluye ningún involucramiento emocional del hablante en la acción. *“El niño se me durmió”* involucra "éticamente" al referente del pronombre *me* en el evento: el niño se durmió y yo proyecto un valor personal (mi ética o mi moral) sobre eso; el niño se durmió y quizá no debía dormirse mientras estaba a mi cuidado, ergo fallé en algo; que el niño se haya dormido me afecta moralmente.

Comment: pablopdf76, ¿que piensa de la frase "me temo que el agua fresca no sea la mejor solución" ? ¿ es la función del "me" aqui un dativo ético ?

Comment: @Mintou No estoy seguro, pero es el que mejor encaja. Una de las características del dativo ético es que se puede quitar el pronombre sin que cambie el significado, cosa que no ocurre con otros tipos de dativos. "Temo que" y "Me temo que" significan lo mismo, pero el segundo muestra un involucramiento personal mayor, así que podría ser un dativo ético.